# copy site collection cross tenant

Tags: site-template, copy-and-paste, cross

Am tring to copy one site colelction from tenant to another tenant.
the export code is the following :

```
$username = 'admin@M365x339xxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
$password = 'pwd'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $securePassword)

#Set variables
$SiteURL = "https://m365x339xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/TheHub"
$SchmaXMLPath = "C:export\test2.xml"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credentials $credential
 
#Get Site Schema with content
Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out $SchmaXMLPath -PersistBrandingFiles -IncludeAllTermGroups  -IncludeAllClientSidePages -IncludeSiteCollectionTermGroup -IncludeSiteGroups -IncludeTermGroupsSecurity -IncludeSearchConfiguration  -IncludeNativePublishingFiles -IncludeHiddenLists
```

my problem here that i feel that i did not get the ressources like images, pages !!!
i got only one folder colled ressources with the logo and anotehr file xml with the template.
the template.xml , doesnot have any information about the pages...

when i import to the destination site with this code:

```
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -interactive 
Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate -Path $SchmaXMLPath -ClearNavigation -OverwriteSystemPropertyBagValues -IgnoreDuplicateDataRowErrors -ProvisionContentTypesToSubWebs -ResourceFolder C:\Users\imen.turki\Desktop\CGIAR\CGIAR\script\export-CGIAR
```

running the import script gives me :

> WARNING: ListInstance Style Library is a Style Library of a site with
> NoScript enabled and will be skipped Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate : The
> current user has insufficient permissions to perform this operation.

I mention that i update the user email at the template